# Prove that a set is closed iff it contains all its accumulation points

Tags: general-topology

Prove that a set is closed iff it contains all its accumulation points.

I have no clue on how to approach the above problem. At first I would appreciate hints on how to get started in either direction $\Leftarrow$ or $\Rightarrow$.

This is how we have def. an accumulation point:

> A point $x \in X$ is called an accumulation point of $A \subset X$ if for every $U \in U_x$ there is $y$ s.t $y \not = x$ with $y \in U \cap A$. Where $U_x =\{ U \in X: U \text{ neighbour of } x \in X\}$

We have def. a closed set to be the complement of an open set.

Comment: there is no y? or there is at least one?

Comment: There is no $y$ such that $y \not =x$, i.e for every $y$ in the intersection between $U$ and $A$, $y$ must be equal to $x$, if $x$ is an accumulation point @DougM

Comment: Check your definition.  You have it nearly backwards  x is an accumulation point in A, if every neighborhood of x contains a point (other than x) in A.

Comment: I dont understand, do you mean that my comment or def. In the post is wrong? @DougM

Comment: your definition is wrong.  It should say "there is" and not "there is no"

Comment: You are right. I assume that your answer is based on "there is"? @DougM

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> $A\subset X$ is closed $\implies A$ contains all its accumulation points.

Proof by contradiction:

$A\subset X$ is closed $\implies X\setminus A$ is open.

$X\setminus A$ is open $\implies \forall x \in X\setminus A,  \exists U_x$ such that $\forall y\in U_x\implies y\in X\setminus A$

Suppose $x$ is an accumulation of $A$ that is not in $A$

$\forall U\in U_x, \exists y\ne x$ with $y \in U\cap A$

$y \in U\cap A \implies y\notin X\setminus A$ -- Contradiction.

> $A\subset X$ contains all of its accumulation points $\implies A$ is closed

The other way -- also by contradiction:

Suppose $A\subset X$ contains all of its accumulation points.

Suppose $X\setminus A$ is not open.

There exists an $x \in X\setminus A$ such that $\forall U\in U_x$ there exists $y \in U$ that is also in $A.$

$x$ is an accumulation point, which contradicts the premise.

${\rm QED}$

Comment: How do you define $X-A$?

Comment: The compliment of A.  I don't know how to make a "\" in latex.

Comment: @DougM It should be "\backslash". (If you still don't know after three years.)

Comment: @DougM On the second to last line, didn't you mean "$\forall U_x$ there exists $y$..." (and not "$\forall U \in U_x$...")? Seems to me that $U_x$ is your notation for neighbourhood of x.

Comment: Also, it's not very hard to adapt the proofs by contradiction to proofs by conttrapositive, cf. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162018/accumulation-points-cluster-points-closed-sets?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a more general proof for a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n $. That is, we prove that

$\mathbf{Statement:}$ if $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n, S$ is closed iff it contains all its limit (a.k.a. accumulation) points.

$\mathbf{Proof:}$

($\Rightarrow $) Consider that $S$ is closed, that is $S \cup \delta S = S $; consider a limit point $x$ in $S$. THere exists a sequence $\{x_n\} \in S $ such that its limit point is $x$. Suppose by contradiction that $x \notin S$; therefore for any open ball $B_r(x)$ and every $n>N$ with $N$ sufficiently large, $ x_n \in B_r(x) \cap S \neq \emptyset$ and $B_r(x) \cap S^c \neq \emptyset$; so that $x \in \delta S$ but $x \notin S$ which is a contradiction.

($\Leftarrow $) Assume now that the set of all limit points in contained in $S$ and prove that $S=\delta S \cup S$. Take $x \in \delta S$; therefore $\forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists\ x_n $ such that $x_n \in B_\frac{1}{n} \cap S$. Consequently, either $x$ is a limit point for $S$ or $x \in S$.

This completes the proof.
$Q.E.D.$

Comment: This is actually *less* general because OP was asking about general topological spaces. Your proof only works in metric spaces :(