# Domain to define a holomorphic function with non-isolated singularities closed, open, neither?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm studying singularities in complex analysis and came across the following function:
$$f(z):=\frac{1}{z\cos(\frac{1}{z})}$$

I already figured out that $f$ has a non-isolated singularity in $0$ and that there are poles in $$z_k:=\frac{2}{\pi(1+2k)}$$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, tending towards $0$ for $|k|\to\infty$. I am now trying to find out if the domain $$D_f:=\mathbb{C}\setminus(\{z_k|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{0\}),$$ is closed, open or neither.

I already came up with a proof that $D_f$ cannot be closed because if $z\in\{z_k|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{0\}$, there is no $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(z_1,\epsilon)\subseteq \{z_k|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{0\}$ due to $z_k\le z_1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Can one help me out with the rest?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, 0 is not a pole but rather a non-isolated singularity...z_k are on the other hand simple poles.  Second, why do you think D_f is not open?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. Actually, I am lacking a proof here... Can one proof that it is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${D_f} = {\Bbb C}\backslash \left( {\left\{ {{z_k}} \right\}_{ - \infty }^\infty  \cup \left\{ 0 \right\}} \right)$ is in fact open.

I believe it is easier to see that $B = \left\{ {{z_k}} \right\}_{ - \infty }^\infty  \cup \left\{ 0 \right\}$ is closed.

According to this:

[Prove that a set is closed iff it contains all its accumulation points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986774/prove-that-a-set-is-closed-iff-it-contains-all-its-accumulation-points)

it suffices to check that $B$ contains all of its accumulation points.

Well the set $B$ has only one accumulation point and it's $0$ and it's contained in $B$.

Thus $B$ is closed and $${D_f} = {\Bbb C}\backslash B$$ is open.

Alternatively we can show that the set $B$ is closed by showing that it contains all of its boundary points.

By the definition of a boundary point ($x$ is a boundary points of $B$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one element in $B$ and at least one element not in $B$) we conclude that every point in $B$ is a boundary point.
Thus $B$ is closed.